# Why is React functional component state not retaining state value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In the following React functional component there is a local emailAttachments state. Initially it is an empty array. There is an event handler that accepts an instance of EmailAttachment which is to be appended to the emailAttachments array.

```
interface EmailAttachemnt {
  emailAttachmentID: number;
  fileName: string;
}

const MemberEmailForm: React.FC<MemberEmailProps> = (props) => {

  const [emailAttachments, setEmailAttachments] = React.useState<Array<EmailAttachment>>([]);
    
  const handleAttachmentAdded = (attachment: EmailAttachment) => {
    const a = [...emailAttachments];
    setEmailAttachments([...a, ...[attachment]]);
  }

}
```

When the handler is called with a new EmailAttachment instance the first time the instance is appended to the empty array. and the UI updated as React senses the state change. (below)

```
      <List>
        {emailAttachments.map((a: EmailAttachment) => (
          <ListItem key={a.emailAttachmentID}>
            <ListItemText primary={a.fileName} />
            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
              <IconButton edge="end" >
                <DeleteIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
```

However, when the event handler is called the second and subsequent times the emailAttachments is an empty array to the emailAttachments array never contains more than one instance, the last one passed to the handler.

The handler initially updated the array using this

```
setEmailAttachments([...emailAttachments, ...[attachment]]);
```

then this approach

```
setEmailAttachments([...emailAttachments, attachment);
```

then after some research this approach where the original array is copied first

```
const a = [...emailAttachments];
setEmailAttachments([...a, ...[attachment]]);
```

However, in both approaches the behavior is the same, the emailAttachments array is always empty when the handler executes.

Is there a more appropriate approach that would result in the subsequent instances being appended and the array containing all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are enqueueing state updates in a loop. Since component state is const and you enqueue a bunch of state updates within a render cycle, you should use a functional state update to update state from the previous state, not the state from the previous render cycle.

[functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setEmailAttachments(emailAttachments => [
  ...emailAttachments,
  ...[attachment],
]);
```

Comment: that solved the problem and will be helpful knowledge for other situations.